# How to get a `readonly string[]` into a `string[]`?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, type-assertion

I have the following data setup (not declaring as an `enum` because this is shared between TypeScript server code and non-TypeScript client code):

```
import { enumType } from 'nexus';

export const TYPE_ENUM = Object.freeze({
  H: 'H',
  S: 'S',
});
export const TYPES = Object.freeze(Object.values(TYPE_ENUM));

export const MyType = enumType({
  name: 'MyType',
  members: TYPES,
});
```

TypeScript is giving me the following warning regarding the `members` field:

```
Type '(readonly string[])[]' is not assignable to type '(string | EnumMemberInfo)[] | Record<string, string | number | boolean | object>'.
  Type '(readonly string[])[]' is not assignable to type '(string | EnumMemberInfo)[]'.
    Type 'readonly string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | EnumMemberInfo'.
      Type 'readonly string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
enumType.d.ts(29, 3): The expected type comes from property 'members' which is declared here on type 'EnumTypeConfig<"MyType">'
```

I understand the error. Can't put a `readonly string[]` into something expecting `string[]` because they are different types. My question, is what is the best way to overcome this?

I've seen that unwrapping and recreating the array works: `members: [...TYPES]` but that feels wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the answer: `members: [...TYPES]` because you need another mutable Array for function `enumType`.

You may feel that something is wrong. But it is not, why?
The function `enumType` expects a mutable Array, it means it can change its content, such as:

```js
function enumType(v: {name: string; members: string[]): string[] {
  v.members.push('JOKER');
  return v.members;
}

export const MyType = enumType({
  name: 'MyType',
  members: TYPES as unknown as string[],
});
// You would expect MyType is ['H', 'S', 'JOKER'] but you are having an error in strict mode as you were trying to add an element to a freezed array
```

If you own the function `enumType` and you know that it does not change the array content, in this case, the function should accept a `readonly string[]`

```js
function enumType({v: {name: string; memebers: readonly string[]}) {
  ...
}
```

If you do not own the function: `members: [...TYPES]` is the best way.

Comment: A bit more declarative: `Array.from(TYPES)`